VMware Workstation 17.5 with 3D Accelerated Graphics
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 and VMware Workstation 17.5.2 and the 3D Accelerated Graphics options does not work on the host.
Whichever VM I try, whichever OS I try to load, I get the error message "No 3D support is available from the host."
This is my processor/graphics:
AMD Ryzen™ 7 PRO 4750U with Radeon™ Graphics × 16
I am using the latest AMD drivers from repo.radeon.com
I've also installed the mesa-2404 drivers from the App Center.
I followed the instructions here:
https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/17/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-EA588485-718A-4FD8-81F5-B6E1F04C5788.html
glxinfo | grep direct
direct rendering: Yes
    GL_AMD_gpu_shader_int64, GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect, 
    GL_ARB_depth_clamp, GL_ARB_derivative_control, GL_ARB_direct_state_access, 
    GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_ARB_draw_indirect, 
    GL_ARB_indirect_parameters, GL_ARB_instanced_arrays, 
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multi_bind, GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect, 
    GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect, GL_AMD_performance_monitor, 
    GL_ARB_direct_state_access, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ARB_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_draw_instanced, GL_ARB_enhanced_layouts, 
    GL_ARB_indirect_parameters, GL_ARB_instanced_arrays, 
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multi_bind, GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect, 
    GL_EXT_direct_state_access, GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, GL_EXT_draw_instanced, 

This used to work previously on this same machine, I believe it was on Ubuntu 22.04.
Thank you!

I am confused in the first part of the question you say no matter what OS it does not work. In the last sentence you say Ubuntu 22.04 did work. Please clarify does nothing work or not?

my host is 24.04, when I had a previous host 22.04 this option used to work.
when I mentioned trying any OS, I was referring to the virtual machines in VMware.
basically the issue is with the host, not the virtual machines.

I found the solution with Chat GPT!
sudo nano /etc/vmware/config

Add these two lines:
mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers = "TRUE"
mks.enable3d = "TRUE"

3D accelerated now, hopefully this will help someone.

So it is not a clear answer it is only a hope?

@David he didn't mean "I hope it works" he said "I hope this will help someone"
